# Not able to load 3rd party JS in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm new to LWC and trying to create a simple LWC component with input field. I have loaded 3rd party zip folder in Static Resource which contain JS and CSS file.

Scenario - If user types street name into input field then I want to populate address suggestion using 3rd party JS library.

Currently I'm not able to populate below is the screenshot.

[image]

Below is the screenshot of component what I'm expecting output using 3rd party JS.

[image]

Below is the code in LWC

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label">Street Address</label>
        <input id="streetAddress" name="streetAddress" class="slds-input" type="text" lwc:dom="manual" placeholder="Address Search" value={postalCodeFieldValue}/>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import addresscompleteResource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/addresscomplete';
export default class VS_PostalCode extends LightningElement {

    postalCodeFieldValue='';
    jsInitialized=false;

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("connectedCallbac1");
        if (this.jsInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.jsInitialized = true;
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, addresscompleteResource + '/addresscomplete.css'),
            loadScript(this, addresscompleteResource + '/addresscomplete.js')
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.callAddressCompleteJS();
            });

    }
    callAddressCompleteJS() {
        var fields = [
            { element: "streetAddress", field: "Line1" }
        ],
            options = {
                key: "UE16-PK48-CT42-MD73"
            },
            control = new pca.Address(fields, options);
        control.listen("populate", function (address) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(address));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm not able to populate street address in input field using 3rd party JS, let me edit question

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: In browser console, I'm not able to see any error but I feel there is issue with LWC Locker service which is blocking DOM modification.

Answer (score 1):

The script can't find the element by Id, so it won't know which element to attach to. At minimum, you need to dynamically grab the Id:

```
const fields = [
  { element: this.template.querySelector('input[name=streetAddress]').id, field: 'Line1' }
];
```

This is required because the ID values are generated dynamically during runtime, so you can't possibly predict the ID ahead of time. I checked the [documentation](https://www.canadapost.ca/pca/support/guides/advanced), it doesn't seem to allow simply passing in an element, which would be ideal, so this is the next best solution.

Alternatively, consider just using their API and writing your own UI; this may be more efficient in terms of ease of use, although this appears to be a metered API, so I can't speak for its cost.

Comment: This answer points to how you need to triage these sorts of errors; use your browser's JavaScript debugger to see what's happening as you step through the code, and to examine the DOM to make sure it looks like what you expect.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I tried your code but still no luck. I think there is issue with LWC locker service. What you say?

Comment: @ChetanNandre I don't have enough information to tell. I would need the error message(s) you're seeing to provide more information. This appears to be a simple script, though I didn't download it to verify (requires registration?). I only provided an answer based on available information. If you're getting problems at this point, it's probably because you didn't set the [CSP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm). We can give you better answers if we knew what errors you got?

Comment: @sfdcfox I have added URL into CSP and I tried using Aura Component and working fine. In browser console, I'm not able to see any error but I feel there is issue with LWC Locker service which is blocking DOM modification

Comment: @ChetanNandre Locker Service is the same between Aura and LWC. If it works in Aura, it should work in LWC.